# Como dizer em português que algo é “relatable”?

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia, estrangeirismos

O verbo “relate” é normalmente traduzido como “relacionar-se”, mas seu uso em inglês expressa uma ideia que é difícil de expressar em português com essa tradução:

> I can relate to that.
>
> That is totally relatable!

Como expressar isso em português? Há alguma palavra ou expressão melhor que “relacionar”? Esses exemplos não me parecem expressar bem a mesma ideia:

> Eu me releciono/posso me relacionar com isso.
>
> Isso é tão relacionável!

Answer (score 10):

O que eu tenho a propor são dois palavrões: ***empatizar*** e ***empatizável***. Os teus exemplos ficariam:

> Consigo empatizar com isso.
> Isso é tão empatizável.

O Aulete online define [***empatizar***](http://www.aulete.com.br/empatizar) como “sentir empatia por,” e define [***empatia***](http://www.aulete.com.br/empatia) como:

> **1.** Psi[cologia] Experiência pela qual uma pessoa se identifica com outra, tendendo a compreender o que ela pensa e a sentir o que ela sente, ainda que nenhum dos dois o expressem de modo explícito ou objetivo.
> **2.** Capacidade de compreensão emocional e estética de um objeto, geralmente, de arte (um quadro, livro, filme, por exemplo).

Isto corresponde à definição relevante de [***to relate to*** no Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/relate-to)

> To be able to understand and have sympathy with someone or something. SYNONYM: empathize with. *Many adults can't relate to children. Our product needs an image that people can relate to.*

Não encontrei ***empatizável*** em qualquer dicionário, mas o termo é muito usado em psicologia e psiquiatria, e já o encontrei usado em contexto mais geral, possivelmente por pessoas que quiseram, tal como nós, encontrar um equivalente português para *relatable*:

> [Acerca do Game of Thrones](http://leituraescrita.com.br/2011/05/09/game-of-thrones-episodio-1-winter-is-coming-hbo/) Também, ao que parece, estão fazendo uma Cersei que é ao menos empatizável. Ela pode ser uma “vilã”, mas também tem seus problemas, como um marido que faz questão de desrespeitá-la.
>
> [Spell: bem e mal em D&D](http://spellrpg.com.br/home/index.php?topic=1613.30) mas não consigo empatizar com esse combate de D&D baseado em buffs/spells/poções/etc.

Agora, se aceitares uma tradução mais livre, em muitos contextos eu usaria algo mais idiomático baseado em ***diz-me muito/qualquer coisa/nada***. O significado relevante de [***dizer*** é o **11** do Aulete:](http://www.aulete.com.br/dizer)

> **11.** Provocar interesse, atração; ter significação para (alguém). [tdi. + a, para : *Esse lugar lhe diz alguma coisa?*]

Alguns exemplos:

> Isso não me diz nada.
>
> Mas esse combate de D&D baseado em buffs/spells/poções/etc. não me diz nada.
>
> Essa música diz-me muito.

Comment: Eu já vi o uso desse verbo no Brasil, como em "me empatizo com isto ou essa pessoa" mas notei agora que esse verbo não consta em dicionários brasileiros. Nós deveríamos ter um tipo de academia de letras supra-nacional.

Comment: @Luciano, o verbo *empatizar* vem nos dicionários (eu cito o Aulete), não vem é com conjugação pronominal: a forma tradicional é *eu empatizo com;* não _*eu **me** empatizo com._ Mas o pessoal tem o direito de inovar :)

Comment: Em boa verdade, acho que nenhuma tradução vai alguma vez parecer satisfatória pois nenhuma palavra em português tem associada a "bagagem" que "relatable" carrega por ser usada como "slang" digital - o que leva sempre à sensação que a palavra, em inglês, codifica uma sensação específica que nunca consegue ser totalmente captada pelas traduções ("relacionar/identificar/empatizar"). Recomendo um artigo que debate a evolução da língua causada pela era digital: https://www.theguardian.com/media-network/2015/jun/26/hashtag-language-evolution-digital-age

Answer (score 9):

No primeiro caso, pode-se usar o verbo **identificar**:

> Eu me identifico com isso.

Não tenho certeza se há algo que expresse bem o segundo.

Comment: Nota: a resposta me veio à cabeça enquanto escrevia a pergunta, por isso já respondi direto. Mas na realidade estou mais interessado na segunda expressão do que na primeira, então respostas melhores serão muito bem-vindas.

Comment: The two English sentences have the same meaning apart from the strength of the sentiment and the grammatical form. For the latter, there is an adjective *identificável*, but I don't know that it can be used this way..? For the former, probably you can toss a *muito* in, right?

Comment: @Frank The tricky part is that *identificar* usually menas "to identify". Something is *identificável* if that thing can be identified, i.e. if its identity can be determined. Likewise, just *eu me identifico*, period, would mean "I identify myself". But when you use *eu me identifico com X* that means (in Brazil, at least) "I relate to X". I guess its an idiom, but I'm not sure. As in "I feel X and I have things in common". Anyway, describing something as "relatable" - not only to myself, but to others as well - is something I don't know how to express well in portuguese.

Comment: "Isso é totalmente algo com que se pode se identificar!" é verboso, mas funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Usaria o termo familiar

Eu me familiarizo com isso.
Isso é tão familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Num contexto do tipo: "His father is older, but still rugged and relatable -- a handsome guy with a heavy laugh", "relatable seria, na minha opinião, algo como "um cara ainda forte e com um bom papo"

Answer (score 0):

Com o que, com o qual se pode ter empatia/identificar:

She is so relatable!
Ela é alguém com a qual se pode facilmente ter empatia!
Ela é alguém com a qual se pode bem identificar/ podemos bem nos identificar!